# Can't populate database table

Tags: c#

```
protected void ButtonAddDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (KnowItCvdbEntities db = new KnowItCvdbEntities())
    {
        SPWeb theSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
        SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
        string strUserName = theUser.LoginName;

        var theEmplDbSkill = (
                        from p
                        in db.EMPLOYEES
                        where p.username == strUserName
                        select p).FirstOrDefault();

        _emp = theEmplDbSkill;

        if (_emp != null)
        {                        
            foreach (var vItem in ListBoxDatabases.Items)
            {
                if (ValueAlreadyInListDb(vItem))
                    return;
            }                        

      //Get existing skilllevel from db
      var skillLevel = (from sL in db.TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL 
                        where sL.technical_skill_level_id == Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListDB.SelectedValue)
                        select sL).FirstOrDefault();

       //Get existing skillvalue from db
        var skillValue = (from sV in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS
                         where sV.technical_skill_id == Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonListDatabase.SelectedValue)
                         select sV).FirstOrDefault();

       //Adding to employees_technical_skills table
       var empSkill = new EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS
       {
            technical_skill_id = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListDB.SelectedItem.Value),
            TECHNICAL_SKILLS = skillValue,
            technical_skill_level_id = Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonListDatabase.SelectedItem.Value)
            TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL = skillLevel,
            employee_id = _emp.employee_id
        }

            _emp.EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS_Add(empSkill);
            db.SaveChanges();

            _emp.EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS.Add(empSkill);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }                
    }
}
```

Right now I'm working on populating the following table:
[image]

This is my tables:
[image]

But I keep getting the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Regards,
Kristian.

Comment: Just suggestion, you need to follow c# coding convention

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `technical_skill_level_id` property has a legitimate value? From the error, it appears that the value is not one that's in the `TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL` table. Maybe the dropdown values are all zero instead of the correct value.

Comment: @CuongLe, I did put my c# code above, should i put more?

Comment: Have you verified the value getting set for the Ids exists in the database table you're referencing? For example, are you passing SkillLevel 37 but the Technical_Skill_Level table only has 1-5?

Comment: When i'm debugging i am getting the right values, but I get the exception on db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Can you add the definition/assignment of `db`?

Comment: instead of using RadioButtonListDatabase.SelectedValue try this :  RadioButtonListDatabase.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: @RyanGates, Updated with whole code. Hope it was it u were looking for! Sorry was on meeting so couldnt read the posts untill now!

Comment: @2GDev, Just tried that, same exception..

Comment: @RyanGates, I've updated the code with the stack trace. Newbie question, what is "ORM"? Could you provide me a link so i can read about it?

Comment: Can you show the values in your `EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS` table?

Comment: FYI: [ORM stands for Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Examples in the .net world include NHibernate, Entity Framework, and others.

Comment: @RyanGates, Right now there are no values, i want to populate that table. Please check the image i just updated with. When i pick something in the dropdownlist, i want to get the `technical_skill_id` from the table `"TECHNICAL_SKILLS"` and when i check something in the radiobuttonlist i want to get the `technical_skill_level_id` from the `"TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL"` table and populate it in the `"EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS"` table.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `_emp.EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS.Add(empSkill);` What are the values of the three properties that you set for empSkill?

Comment: @RyanGates, `employee_id = 4, technical_skill_id = 2, technical_skill_level_id = 1` but both `TECHNICAL_SKILLS & TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL` is null. But my `employees_technical_skills_id` is 0.. That isn't right, should i also populate with `employees_technical_skills_id = new Random().Next();` in my object initializer?

Comment: @RyanGates, Can't really get it right :(

Comment: @RyanGates, Thought i had it, but not.. Getting the following error now: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Entity framework can't convert `Convert.ToInt32()` to an SQL expression.  I would convert the radiobutton and dropdown values to `int` in memory first, then pass them to the queries:

```
int TechnicalSkillLevelID = int.Parse(DropDownListDB.SelectedValue);
int TechnicalSkillID = int.Parse(RadioButtonListDatabase.SelectedValue);
//Get existing skilllevel from db
      var skillLevel = (from sL in db.TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL 
                        where sL.technical_skill_level_id == TechnicalSkillLevelID)
                        select sL).FirstOrDefault();

       //Get existing skillvalue from db
        var skillValue = (from sV in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS
                         where sV.technical_skill_id == TechnicalSkillID)
                         select sV).FirstOrDefault();

       //Adding to employees_technical_skills table
       var empSkill = new EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS
       {
            technical_skill_id = skillValue.technical_skill_id,
            TECHNICAL_SKILLS = skillValue,
            technical_skill_level_id = skillLevel.technical_skill_level_id)
            TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL = skillLevel,
            employee_id = _emp.employee_id
        }
```

Also, since you already pulled back the skill levels and skill values, no need to grab the values from the drop down / radio button list.  Just use the `skillValue` and `skillLevel` objects.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, eastern weekend hehe. But i did the same like you and it works =)